# Twitter like function for SharePoint 2007

Tags: untagged

Is there an application that can be added to SharePoint 2007 to provide microblogging capability?

I have seen several applications that do this but not as an addin to SharePoint. One I have found is Kiro but wondering if there are others.

Comment: I want to know this as well. Interesting idea. We are also looking at SharePoint 2010 -- are there components that might work on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 has that functionality out of the box. For 2007 take a look at [Discussion Central](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2009/12/08/announcing-discussion-central-for-sharepoint.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Have contacted Discussion Central.  Do you have a link to that feature in SharePoint 2010?  Have been going through the MS site with no sucess.

Answer (score 2):

Zevenseas have created a similar webpart, and i believe it is open source. They are also behind Discussion central. have a look at

[team status](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2009/05/09/release-version-of-our-%e2%80%9cassembly-free%e2%80%9d-team-status-template.aspx)